# iPhoto face recognition algorithm

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I'm writing a project in which we need to be able to recognize faces using OpenCV. I'm training my base on photos, then give test photos to the program with people, which we attended. Recognition works good (80-90%). But! If I give the program a photo with person, which we didn't use in the teaching of our base, the program finds a man in our base with the terrible low distance. At the same time, Apple iPhoto works good with all photos. Can anyone know what algorithm they used to recognize faces ? or had my problem? Help please.

P.S. Tested algorithms: LBPHFaceRecognizer, FisherFaceRecognizer, EigenFaceRecognizer.

Answer (score 1):

You mention iPhoto so I'm going to assume you're using OS X or iOS. If so, you may want to try [Apple's built-in face detection](http://www.panic.com/blog/2012/11/fun-with-face-recognition/).

Comment: No, I do not use apple. iPhoto have a sample program performs correctly the features I need to implement